# Trying to downoad images from a website but the loop never end why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using mshtml;

namespace Extract_Images
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string[] linkstoextract;
        private int numberoflinks;
        private int currentLinkNumber = 1;
        private string mainlink;
        private WebClient client;
        private WebBrowser webBrowser1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
            label1.Text = "Number of links: ";
            mainlink = "http://www.test.com";
            numberoflinks = 211;
            ProcessNextLink();

        }

        private void ProcessNextLink()
        {
            if (currentLinkNumber < numberoflinks)
            {
                currentLinkNumber++;
                string linktonav = mainlink + "index"+currentLinkNumber.ToString() + ".html";
                webBrowser1.Navigate(linktonav);
            }
        }

        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessImagesFromDocument();
            ProcessNextLink();
        }


        private void ProcessImagesFromDocument()
        {
            IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
            IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)doc.body).createControlRange();

            foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
            {
                imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement)img);
                imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);

                using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                {
                    if (bmp != null)
                    {
                        bmp.Save(@"d:\files\savedlinks\" + img.nameProp);
                        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                    }
                }
            }

        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

In the part:

```
using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                {
                    if (bmp != null)
                    {
                        bmp.Save(@"d:\files\savedlinks\" + img.nameProp);
                        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                    }
                }
```

Even if the bmp is not null after one iteration i'm getting exception on the bmp.Save line: Illegal characters in path

And i see in nameProp 395937.thumb?d=1348638415

The other problem is if i'm not using the lines:

```
bmp.Save(@"d:\files\savedlinks\" + img.nameProp);
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

If i delete this two lines and using break point on the line:

```
if (bmp != null)
```

It will keep stop on this line for ever it will never stop it will keep stop on this line over and over again it will not stop on the foreach but only on this line.

What i want to do is to download from each link the images and also to make it optional to download specific images types like only jpg or only png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illegal characters in path error is because your file name is not a valid file name to save because it has invalid character like: '?'

Why the loop is endless, this need more debugging, Debug your code step by step, check the number of images on the first loop,

- is it a huge unexpected number of images?
- does the number increase on each loop? -> this may be a referencing issue.

Comment: Right there are 326 images. So now i know why it's taking so long. And how can i filter to make that it will save bmp.Save only jpg type images ?

Comment: I think you can do that by checking the file name extension, using Path class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx